# How to slideToggle a current element sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a sibling on click of current sibling, at the same time other open .stcontent   should close but change in the structure of the html code **html**

```js
// handle click and add class
$(".stbtn").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings(".wrapper").child(".stcontent").slideUp();
  $(this).siblings(".stcontent").slideToggle();
})
```

```css
.stbtn {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.stbtn,
.stcontent {}

.stcontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stbtn">
    slide Toggle btn1
  </div>
  <div class="stcontent">
    slide Toggle btn content here goes1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stbtn">
    slide Toggle btn2
  </div>
  <div class="stcontent">
    slide Toggle btn content here goes1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stbtn">
    slide Toggle btn3
  </div>
  <div class="stcontent">
    slide Toggle btn content here goes1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/72mg9x77/, Use `children()` not `child()`

Comment: Why not keep it simple. Close all opened ones first and then open the one which got a click ... https://jsfiddle.net/chrvfntf/1/ ? is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to achieve the same:

```
// handle click and add class
    $(".stbtn").on("click", function(){
    $('.wrapper').children('.stcontent').hide();
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').children().show();
    });
```

OR

```
 $(".stbtn").on("click", function(){
    $('.wrapper').children('.stcontent').slideUp();
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').children().slideDown();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below line to toggle `div` smoothly

```
$(this).parent().find(".stcontent").slideToggle();
```

Code snippet:

```js
// handle click and add class
$(".stbtn").on("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings(".wrapper").children(".stcontent").slideUp();
  $(this).parent().find(".stcontent").slideToggle();
})
```

```css
.stbtn { background-color:#ccc; margin-bottom:5px;}
.stbtn, .stcontent {  }
.stcontent { display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stbtn">
    slide Toggle btn1
  </div>
  <div class="stcontent">
    slide Toggle btn content here goes1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stbtn">
    slide Toggle btn2
  </div>
  <div class="stcontent">
    slide Toggle btn content here goes1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stbtn">
  slide Toggle btn3
  </div>
  <div class="stcontent">
  slide Toggle btn content here goes1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine

```
$('.stbtn').on('click', function() {
    var activeParent = $(this).parent('.wrapper');
    $('.wrapper').not(activeParent).children('.stcontent').slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('.stcontent').slideToggle();
})
```